# How to solve a linear differential equation with Green's function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

My exercise is to solve the differential equation
$$(x+1)y''(x)+xy'(x)-y(x)=1$$
With the boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=0$, and using it's Green's function.
On a physics class, we were solving the $u''(t)+2\beta u(t)+\omega_0^2u(t)=f(t)$ the following way:

The operator is $$L(D)=D^2+2\beta D+\omega_0^2$$
and the green function is $$G(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega \frac{1}{2\pi L(i\omega)}e^{i\omega t}$$
And then the solution is
$$u(t)=\int \mathrm{d}\tau f(\tau)G(t-\tau)$$

But now, the $L(D)$ is dependent on $x$ as well: $L(D)=(x+1)D^2+xD-1$, so the Green's function is:
$$G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega \frac{1}{2\pi L(i\omega)}e^{i\omega x}$$
$$G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{-(x+1)\omega^2+i\omega x -1}e^{i\omega x}$$

Is it right? Should I just evaluate that integral and go on?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the Fourier transform, you should consider that
$$
x^n\rightarrow \left(i\frac{d}{d\omega}\right)^n\qquad \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\rightarrow(-i\omega)^n.
$$
So, after Fourier transform, you get again a differential equation given by
$$
\left(i\frac{d}{d\omega}+1\right)[(-i\omega)^2{\hat G(\omega)}]
+i\frac{d}{d\omega}[-i\omega{\hat G(\omega)}]-{\hat G(\omega)}=1.
$$

Comment: I know this, but my task would be to solve it with Green's function. Couls you help me with that?

Comment: Or should I just solve that differential equation for $G$?

Comment: What I wrote is the equation for the Green function. The Fourier transformed Green function cannot depend on $x$ in any case. You have to solve this first order ode and then back-transform.

Comment: I realized it meanwhile, thanks. And the solution will be $y(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(x-t) \mathrm{d}t$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Can I also apply Laplace transform instead of Fourier, or that would cause some problem?

Comment: No, It should not.

Comment: Why do you have $1$ on the rhs? Should not I transform that as well?

Comment: It is the Fourier transform of the Dirac $\delta$. This comes out from the definition of Green function.

Comment: If I did not miss anything in my calculations, the result for G(x) has an Ei(x) with FT (solved with WolframAlpha), and constant*x+constant + (x+1)*u(x+1) with LT. So the first one is a really hard integral and the second is divergent. Did I miss something?